# How to navigate to another Tab from via onTap() callback of another Tab of the same TabBarView parent?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. This is my TabBarView.

I have 2 TabView - BuyerAccountBody() & SellerAccountBody()

I want to navigate via onTap() callback of a Widget in the BuyerAccountBody() to SellerAccountBody()

The code to the BuyerAccountBody() is below, where the onTap() callback in the LisTile should navigate to the 2nd TapBarView [i.e, SellerAccountBody() ]

```
class MyAccountView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Account'),
          actions: [],
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelStyle: kButtonTextStyle,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            tabs: [
              Text(
                'BUYER'),
              Text(
                'SELLER'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [      
            
            BuyerAccountBody(),

            ''' **To this Tab**
            SellerAccountBody(),
            '''
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

2. BuyerAccountBody() Widget.

---

```
class BuyerAccountBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BuyerAccountBodyState createState() => _BuyerAccountBodyState();
}

class _BuyerAccountBodyState extends State<BuyerAccountBody> {
  TabController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          
          // ACCOUNT SETTINGS
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  child: Text(
                    'Account Settings',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
               Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('Manage Your Seller Account'),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),

                    ''' **Navigate from here.........**
                    onTap: () {},
                    '''
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onTap: () => DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1)
```